# How can I make this pattern repeat as many times as needed without making it excessively nested?

Tags: c++, formatting, output, hierarchy

I have this function meant to show a hierarchy for a ranking system. I want the hierarchy to be able to be nested as many times as I want. But nesting all these 'for/if' statements seems unnecessary.  Does anyone have some tips on writing functions that are meant to repeat themselves like this?

```
void hierarchy(int x)
{
    cout << "HIERARCHY OF COMMAND: " << member[x].name << ", " << member[x].rnk << " [# "      << member[x].ID << "]\n";
    for (int a = 0; a < member_count; a++)
    {
        if (member[x].name == member[a].CO)
        {
            cout << "|---" << member[a].name << ", " << member[a].rnk << " [# "
                 << member[a].ID << "]\n";
            for (int b = 0; b < member_count; b++)
            {
                if (member[a].name == member[b].CO)
                {
                    cout << "|   |---" << member[b].name << ", " << member[b].rnk << " [# "
                         << member[b].ID << "]\n";
                    for (int c = 0; c < member_count; c++)
                    {
                        if (member[b].name == member[c].CO)
                        {
                            cout << "|   |   |---" << member[c].name << ", " << member[c].rnk << " [# "
                                 << member[c].ID << "]\n";
                            for (int d = 0; d < member_count; d++)
                            {
                                if (member[c].name == member[d].CO)
                                {
                                    cout << "|   |   |   |---" << member[d].name << ", " << member[d].rnk << " [# "
                                         << member[d].ID << "]\n";
                                    for (int e = 0; e < member_count; e++)
                                    {
                                        if (member[d].name == member[e].CO)
                                        {
                                            cout << "|   |   |   |   |---" << member[e].name << ", " << member[e].rnk << " [# "
                                                 << member[e].ID << "]\n";
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ever heard of [Recursion] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) ?

Comment: It seems you need to use recursion http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/D2N36Up4/

Answer (score 2):

User [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) or a [stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29) to solve such problems. Try implementing it. If you face a problem, please post.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the code is running 5 nested loops. Even if you replace this code with analog recursive code it will still be grossly inefficient. If `member_count` is relatively small (less than say 200) then you can get away with this inefficiency, but if it grows bigger the code will run painfully slow.

You should better organize your data. Currently you have a sort of adjacency list, where each array element has information about one edge in the graph (the CO). You should add one more information to the element, which would be the list, and this list would have the opposite information (to whom is this element the CO). These lists (for every element) is built in one run through the array.

When these lists are built you can run that recursive function that other people are talking about. And it will be much faster.

Comment: At the most I'm sure member_count will stay below 200. Its limit is 1000. But I'm not sure what you mean by better organizing my data. This is really the first time I've used classes in anything. And I'm still learning how to keep my programs organized and efficient.

Comment: If you do what is written in second paragraph, and use that new information, the code will run faster, because it would not have to search for information, because it would already have it. So, add the list of direct underlings to each `member` element.